# Multidimensional array, loop of buttons, and loading swf/img/txt from xml

Tags: actionscript-3, multidimensional-array, nested-loops

Okay, here goes: What I'm trying to do is create a multidimensional array which will pull text, swfs, and/or images from an xml file based on which button is clicked.

What I don't understand is how to pull the swf or image file from the file like I have with the text. Truth be told, I'm completely lost and could really use some help fixing this. I need to pull text and images or the swf file from the xml depending on which button is clicked and I tried to put this together, but I've given myself a headache trying to understand where I went wrong.

```
var pageXML:XML;

//Load the XML file.
var pageXMLLoader = new URLLoader();
pageXMLLoader.load(new URLRequest("scripts/xml/content.xml"));
pageXMLLoader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, xmlIOErrorHandler); 
pageXMLLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, pageXMLLoaded);

// Intro page variables for title
var swfContainer:Sprite = new Sprite();
var imgContainer:Sprite = new Sprite();
var imgLoader:Loader = new Loader();
var swfLoader:Loader = new Loader();

//This function is called when the XML file is loaded
function pageXMLLoaded(e:Event):void {

    //Create a new XML object from the loaded XML data
    pageXML = new XML(e.target.data);
    imgLoader.load(new URLRequest(pageXML.pages.page.image));
    swfLoader.load(new URLRequest(pageXML.pages.page.swfURL));
    trace(pageXML.pages.page.image);
    trace(pageXML.pages.page.swfURL);

}

// Choose page transition function
function choosePageTransition(e:MouseEvent):void {
    var pageNumber:uint;

    mcContent.y = 30; // Why do I need to reset the y position each time?

// Set up if for mouse click
if (e.type == MouseEvent.CLICK) {

    // Switch based on target name
    switch (e.currentTarget.name) {
        case "navBtn0" :
            trace(e.currentTarget.name);
            pageNumber = 1;

            mcContent.removeChildAt(0);

            mcContent.addChildAt(pageContent,0);

            pageContent.addChild(contentRBottomTxt);
            pageContent.addChild(contentRTopTxt);
            pageContent.addChild(contentTxt);
            pageContent.addChild(headingTxt);

            break;

        case "navBtn1" :
            trace(e.currentTarget.name);
            pageNumber = 2;

            mcContent.removeChildAt(0);

            mcContent.addChildAt(pageContent,0);

            pageContent.addChild(contentRBottomTxt);
            pageContent.addChild(contentRTopTxt);
            pageContent.addChild(contentTxt);
            pageContent.addChild(headingTxt);

            break;

        case "navBtn2" :
            trace(e.currentTarget.name);
            pageNumber = 3;

            mcContent.removeChildAt(0);

            mcContent.addChildAt(pageContent,0);

            pageContent.addChild(contentRBottomTxt);
            pageContent.addChild(contentRTopTxt);
            pageContent.addChild(contentTxt);
            pageContent.addChild(headingTxt);

            break;

        ... code shortened 
    }


    // Loop through the XML file
    for each (var page:XML in pageXML.pages.page) {

        // "page.@pagenumber" points to "pagenumber" in the XML file.
        if (page.@ pagenumber == pageNumber) {

            // Set the title
            headingTxt.htmlText = page.title;

            // Set the page content
            contentTxt.htmlText = page.content;
            contentRTopTxt.htmlText = page.contenttr;
            contentRBottomTxt.htmlText = page.contentbr;

            // Exit the loop
            break;
        }
    } // < /For Loop >

    } // < /If Statement >
} // < /Function >
```

My xml file looks somewhat like this (it's long, so I'll post a partial):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<site>

    <!--<sitetitle><![CDATA[<strong>Transplant the Heart</strong>]]></sitetitle>-->

    <pages>

        <page pagenumber="1">

            <title><![CDATA[<h1>Page #1</h1>]]></title>

            <content><![CDATA[<p>Aliquam nec dui neque. Aenean rutrum suscipit turpis vel fringilla. </p>]]></content>

            <contenttr><![CDATA[Cras non risus nisi. Nam tincidunt lacinia massa, vel interdum massa ultricies.]]></contenttr>

            <contentbr><![CDATA[Aliquam erat volutpat. Etiam eget mauris ante, sit amet placerat tortor.]]></contentbr>

            <image>imgs/png/titleLarge.png</image>

            <swfURL>transplantSpecialists.swf</swfURL>

        </page>

    </pages>

</site>
```

Comment: Do I need to clarify something further?

Comment: Perhaps the error you are getting at compile/run time?

Comment: I'm getting the Error #2044: Unhandled IOErrorEvent:. text=Error #2035: URL Not Found.

I know this has to do with an incorrect path/filename, the problem is, I've checked, rechecked, and checked again. My files are named exactly the same as written and they're in the directory pointed to. Someone said it may be pointing at a file that doesn't exist, but I don't see where that may be at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you have the correct structure? Something like this ...

```
project folder
  | main.swf
  | scripts/
    | xml/
      | content.xml
  | imgs/
    | png/
      | titleLarge.png
  | transplantSpecialists.swf
```

Comment: Yep, that's my structure. It's so strange. I'm not sure what's going on.

Comment: I believe, what happens is it's trying to pull a swf from one of the nodes that doesn't actually have a swf and/or image file. So it's throwing that error. So what I'm going to do is try to figure out the code you provided on my other question and piece it together so that it works.

I may be too new to AS to be trying this type of thing, but I have to learn some time,eh.